Simulating slow connection with tc but what is burst?
Using Ubuntu 24.04.1 and tc
I am trying to emulate a slower cellular network that is 256kbps and 500ms for both inbound and outbound. I considered using Wondershaper but Latency is not supported and so I've taken this question asked before for inspiration: Simulating a slow connection with tc
I'm a bit lost on the "burst" as it appears to be mandatory and I am not sure what it is supposed to be in my case.  I have the following command in mind - I understand that this is only for shaping egress and will focus on this only for now, policing will come later.
tc qdisk add dev wlp0s20f3 root handle 1: tbf rate 256kbit latency 500ms burst [MISSING BURST HERE]

I found this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100785/bucket-size-in-tbf
It seems I can calculate the rate as:
256000 bits/sec ÷ 1000 = 256 bits (32 bytes)
1000 Hz was determined via:
$ egrep '^CONFIG_HZ_[0-9]+' /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_HZ_1000=y

So I attempted this qdisc as the egress rule first:
tc qdisk add dev wlp0s20f3 root tbf rate 256kbit latency 500ms burst 32
But the connection seems to die (I am running a speed test in the browser as a test) and there is no communication to/from the speedtest server.
It is only when I use a burst of 1500 (unit is bytes I believe) that I see download  start working as 25Mbps (seems to be my max over wlan even without tc) but the Upload shows 0.0?!
tc qdisk add dev wlp0s20f3 root tbf rate 256kbit latency 500ms burst 1500

When I up burst even more to 2000 (bytes) that is when I see download 25Mbps and upload as 0.25Mbps - and looks reasonable?
tc qdisk add dev wlp0s20f3 root tbf rate 256kbit latency 500ms burst 2000

I feel I am just setting burst to an arbitrary number to see things work, not the quite the way I want to work when it comes to testing software. If anyone can shine some light, that would be much appreciated!
